# Convert Linux shell script for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, shell, split, posix

How do we convert the below shell script so that the same result can be achieved on Mac OS X?

```
# To generate secure SSH deploy key for a github repo to be used from Travis
# https://gist.github.com/floydpink/4631240
base64 --wrap=0 ~/.ssh/id_rsa_deploy > ~/.ssh/id_rsa_deploy_base64
ENCRYPTION_FILTER="echo \$(echo \"- secure: \")\$(travis encrypt \"\$FILE='\`cat $FILE\`'\" -r floydpink/harimenon.com)"
split --bytes=100 --numeric-suffixes --suffix-length=2 --filter="$ENCRYPTION_FILTER" ~/.ssh/id_rsa_deploy_base64 id_rsa_

# To reconstitute the private SSH key once running inside Travis (typically from 'before_script')
echo -n $id_rsa_{00..30} >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa_base64
base64 --decode --ignore-garbage ~/.ssh/id_rsa_base64 > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
echo -e "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

I could figure out the equivalent `base64` command to be:

```
base64 --break=0 id_rsa_deploy > id_rsa_deploy_base64
```

But it looks like the [split command on Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/split.1.html) is a little different from Linux/Unix and does not have the `--filter` option.

EDIT: This is [a gist](https://gist.github.com/lukewpatterson/4242707) I stumbled on to from [this blog entry](http://darvin.github.io/2013/01/13/Prose_Octopress_TravisIO/) that details how to auto-deploy an [Octopress](http://octopress.org/) blog to GitHub using [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/).

I had successfully done this from Ubuntu Linux and [had blogged about it](http://www.harimenon.com/blog/2013/01/27/auto-deploying-to-my-octopress-blog/) as well in the past, but could not repeat it from a Mac.

Comment: Example output of the 'good' `split --filter ...` included **in your question** would go along way to helping people think about alternate solutions. As it is now, I/we have to guess. Can you use something like `awk '{while length($0) > 100) {printf("%100s\n", $0); sub(/.{100}/, "", $0 ) # or somesuch ; } printf("%s\n" $0)}' ` as a substitute for `split --bytes=100`? Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @shellter. This script is something I found as [a gist](https://gist.github.com/lukewpatterson/4242707) that would help create the secure GitHub deployment keys for [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/). My n00b-ness to shell scripting and bash commands are the reason the question is as poor as it is. I shall try the `awk` method and update here. Thanks once again... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to install core-utils from [brew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation) (The missing package manager for OS X) and then use **gsplit**:

```
$ brew install coreutils
$ gsplit --help
Usage: gsplit [OPTION]... [INPUT [PREFIX]]
Output fixed-size pieces of INPUT to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...; default
size is 1000 lines, and default PREFIX is 'x'.  With no INPUT, or when INPUT
is -, read standard input.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -a, --suffix-length=N   generate suffixes of length N (default 2)
      --additional-suffix=SUFFIX  append an additional SUFFIX to file names.
  -b, --bytes=SIZE        put SIZE bytes per output file
  -C, --line-bytes=SIZE   put at most SIZE bytes of lines per output file
  -d, --numeric-suffixes[=FROM]  use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic.
                                   FROM changes the start value (default 0).
  -e, --elide-empty-files  do not generate empty output files with '-n'
      --filter=COMMAND    write to shell COMMAND; file name is $FILE
  -l, --lines=NUMBER      put NUMBER lines per output file
  -n, --number=CHUNKS     generate CHUNKS output files.  See below
  -u, --unbuffered        immediately copy input to output with '-n r/...'
      --verbose           print a diagnostic just before each
                            output file is opened
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```

Comment: I started using Mac only recently, and have used brew for some of the other commands! But it never occured to check there. Thank you!